# Minimum map marker interval equation

Tags: javascript, math, maps, equation

I would like to have an equation to calculate, per zoom level on the canonical flat map projection of the earth, what the minimum spacing (in meters) that a map marker can be placed without overlapping, given the dimensions of the marker. Alas, I am no mathematician. Any takers?

For instance:
Zoom level 5 (pretty far out, about continent level), marker dims: 30x30 = 80000 meters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the haversine formula for calculating distance between two points on a map. Then just apply the minimum distance based on your zoom/how big your pins are on your map.

```
function haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371000; // m
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1)* Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1)* Math.PI / 180;
    var lat1 = lat1* Math.PI / 180;
    var lat2 = lat2* Math.PI / 180;

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Note that the R is in meters and you'll need to change it to miles/kms based on whatever you require as a distance.